# ERROR: Solver (gurobi) returned non-zero return code (1)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to solve a national scale energy model using the solver Gurobi but this error comes out and I don't really know how to solve it.

I tried the same problem with the solver glpk for a subset time and it is working, giving though a warning of INFEASIBLE solution. I would like to fix Gurobi problem since I have to run the code at least for a year and with glpk would not be feasible.

```
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: f
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: o
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: u
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: n
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: d
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: (
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: u
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: s
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: e
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: r
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: z
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: e
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: q
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: i
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: r
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: ,
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: h
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: o
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: s
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: t
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: P
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: C
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: ,
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: h
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: o
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: s
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: t
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: i
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: d
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: c
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 8
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 7
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 6
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 1
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 7
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: b
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: b
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: ,
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: c
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: o
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: r
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: e
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: s
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 4
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: )
[2019-01-28 23:04:26] ERROR: 
ERROR: Solver (gurobi) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR: See the solver log above for diagnostic information.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ApplicationError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-640ff0f5af65> in <module>
----> 1 model.run()

~\Miniconda3\pkgs\calliope-0.6.3-py_3\site-packages\calliope\core\model.py in run(self, force_rerun, **kwargs)
    198 
    199         results, self._backend_model, interface = run_backend(
--> 200             self._model_data, self._timings, **kwargs
    201         )
    202 

~\Miniconda3\pkgs\calliope-0.6.3-py_3\site-packages\calliope\backend\run.py in run(model_data, timings, build_only)
     44         results, backend = run_plan(
     45             model_data, timings,
---> 46             backend=BACKEND[run_backend], build_only=build_only
     47         )
     48 

~\Miniconda3\pkgs\calliope-0.6.3-py_3\site-packages\calliope\backend\run.py in run_plan(model_data, timings, backend, build_only, backend_rerun)
     90         results = backend.solve_model(
     91             backend_model, solver=solver,
---> 92             solver_io=solver_io, solver_options=solver_options, save_logs=save_logs
     93         )
     94 

~\Miniconda3\pkgs\calliope-0.6.3-py_3\site-packages\calliope\backend\pyomo\model.py in solve_model(backend_model, solver, solver_io, solver_options, save_logs, **solve_kwargs)
    186     with redirect_stdout(LogWriter('solver', strip=True)):
    187         with redirect_stderr(LogWriter('error', strip=True)):
--> 188             results = opt.solve(backend_model, tee=True, **solve_kwargs)
    189 
    190     return results

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py in solve(self, *args, **kwds)
    594                     logger.error("Solver log:\n" + str(_status.log))
    595                 raise pyutilib.common.ApplicationError(
--> 596                     "Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)
    597             solve_completion_time = time.time()
    598             if self._report_timing:

ApplicationError: Solver (gurobi) did not exit normally
```

Comment: You'll have to show us your code to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: This looks like a Gurobi licensing error, but I agree with @mypetlion, there is not much we can do to help without some form of a reproducible example.